# Comparison-based computation: percentage of current software development?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, comparison

Vol. III of The Art of Computer Programming, chapter 5 (Sorting, intro) mentions:

> Computer manufacturers of the 1960s estimated that more than 25
> percent of the running time on their computers was spent on sorting,
> when all their customers were taken into account. In fact, there were
> many installations in which the task of sorting was responsible for
> more than half of the computing time.

I am looking for stats on *current day* use of comparison-based algorithms (so not only sorting and searching). Does anyone know of reports that might reflect what percentage of computation currently is estimated to involve comparison-based computation (percentage in running time or percentage of code development)? It could be company specific or regard research articles that looked into this issue.

I found [one link](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2011/07/04/sorting/) discussing the topic.

Comment: Comparisons being used to terminate recursion and looping, the share may be high.

Comment: To clarify: I mean pure comparison-based algorithms (in the traditional sense), as opposed to using comparisons for specific goals.